# how to reduce the cpu consumption of my application

Tags: java, tomcat, profiling, connection-pooling, c3p0

For some time now,my app started to have a very large CPU consumption. For some time now, my application started to have a very large CPU consumption. I installed JProfiler, and from what I understand it, there is a problem with hibernate's c3p0. I'm using hibernate 4.3, jsf2.2.10 + primefaces 5.2,tomcat 8.5, use ehcache as well.

Here are some of the results I've printed.

[image: imagem consumo mchange]

[image: Threads .data]

[image: thread tree]

[image: hibernate config]

Answer (score 5):

You can change to using [Hikari](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Pool-Analysis) connection pool,

See Brett Wooldridge's C3P0 Pool Analysis:

> We count over 230 uses of synchronized blocks and methods, and wait() and notifyAll() across various classes. Compare to 0 for HikariCP and Vibur-DBCP which employ lock-free designs. Extensive and wide spread use of locks leads to deadlock-prone code, and evidence of this can be found by Googling "c3p0 deadlock".
>
> We do give C3P0 credit for seemingly covering all of the fundamentals. Unfortunately, C3P0 also consistently comes in last in every one of the microbenchmarks.
>
> **Unsafe Defaults**
> By default does not:
>
> test connections at getConnection() time

Comment: Thanks, I will go test.

Comment: @MarlucioPires will be great if you update with the results